# How can I consolidate data from a group of remote SQL Server instances?

Tags: sql-server, iis

I work for a company whose point-of-sale service uses IIS servers tied to static IP addresses at each of our stores. My boss wants a better real-time stat tracker than what the point-of-sale service provides.

I would like to connect to these servers from a central location and retrieve the data. If possible, I'd like to be able to do so from Python, PHP, or Ruby. What are some recommended approaches for doing so.

Comment: First, find the driver for the language of your choice. Thats really the first step for *any* database connection. Beyond that, its just another relational database.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - are you having problems finding the servers?  Accessing and or interfacing with the MS SQL DBs?

Comment: The methods for accessing MSSQL should be very similar to the other databases; you just have to establish a connection first.  There are libraries that will help you do that; see https://code.google.com/p/pymssql/, https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/, https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds, etc.  My Google searches were "Python MSSQL" and "Ruby MSSQL".

Comment: @GlenH7 accessing/interfacing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation, not a conceptual programming topic.

Comment: Where did you start with MySQL?  Do the same thing, only with MSSQL.

Comment: Are you able to access the servers for each store from your central location? I'm assuming they have some sort of protection from a firewall. They may be able to connect to the central office, but the central office may not be able to connect to each store. You have to setup your network to make that happen.

Comment: @anwyatt I rephrased the question so it better meets the guidelines. Let me know if I lost the original intent of the question in the translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to expose a MS SQL Database to a remote client is to use WCF Data Services. Using Visual Studio, you can walk through a wizard that looks at the database and creates the service for you in minutes.

WCF Data Services exposes your data using an open protocol called OData. There is a consumer library for Ruby that will consume an OData service and allow you to do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This is the *simplest* way?  Or are you suggesting it because it's the latest and greatest?

Comment: It's the most straight forward in that it involves the least amount of custom coding. You literally have a service up and running in minutes.

Comment: @MikeBrown This sounds very cool. I was able to get pyodbc to work, but if I I can use this with Ruby instead I think I would prefer that. I'll look into it for sure. Thanks!